# Check if current seconds is inbetween start and end time

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, dayjs

I have a video player which is returning **seconds** while playing video. Now I have startTime and endTime which are in **HH:mm:ss:ss** format **(eg. 00:06:29:50)**. I want to check if the current second is in between the startTime and endTime.

I tried to convert seconds and startTime/Endtime into unix format using dayJS but it won't work. Can someone please provide me a better idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+time+within+range+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Converting HH:mm:as to a number of seconds is some multiplication and addition.

Comment: Apart from the dupes: https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-between